# TextToSpeech reading Math arithmetic symbols

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I use TextToSpeech to read arithmetic symbols, such as: **add, subtract, multiply and divide** by let TextToSpeech read these texts below :

```
+  : (for add)
-  : (for subtract)
*  : (for multiply)
/  : (for divide)
```

But it seems it does not recognize these words as math arithmetic operations symbols, it reads another word.

How can I make TextToSpeech recognize make these symbols spoken out as an arithmetic operator and read it as I expect?

**Add** : +
**Subtract** : -
**Multiply** : *
**Divide** : /

Comment: Added as an answer, so that you can accept it and remove the post from the Unanswered Question Queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply replace the symbols by their words... i.e. let `"+"` become `"plus"` and so on.